# Change Azure App Service app pool identity

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, trustedconnection

I am hosting an MVC web application in Azure App Service with Azure AD synching with our on prem AD.  I need the app pool to run under a specific account so I can access our on prem SQL Server (via trusted connection).  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ever get an answer to this?

Comment: Could you elaborate or post a link please?

Comment: Any luck on this? I m having the same issue in one of my application.